# When and how to instantiate a Spring Bean in my Rest Api

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-bean

First of all, I'm a relative noob to Spring Boot, so keep that in mind.

I've got a REST api in which I'm trying to minimize database calls for the same object and I've determined that using a Spring Bean scoped to the Request is what I want. Assuming that is correct, here is what I'm trying to do:

1) Controller takes in a validated `PhotoImportCommandDto` command

**PhotoCommandController**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> importPhoto(@Valid @RequestBody PhotoImportCommandDto command){
...
}
```

2) `PhotoImportCommandDto` is validated. Note the custom `@UserExistsConstraint` which validates that the user exists in the database by calling a service method.

**PhotoImportCommandDto**

```
@Component
public class PhotoImportCommandDto extends BaseCommand {

    @NotNull(message = "userId must not be null!")
    @UserExistsConstraint
    private Long userId;
...
}
```

What I would like to do is somehow set a Spring Bean of the user that is validated in the `@UserExistsConstraint` and reference it in various methods that might be called throughout a Http request, but I'm not really sure how to do that. Since I've never really created my own Spring Beans, I don't know how to proceed. I've read various guides like [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes), but am still lost in how to implement it in my code.

Any help/examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: you should use spring data jpa

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Bean` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

@Bean({"validUser"}) 
public User validUser() {
    User user;
    //instantiate user either from DB or anywhere else
    return user;
}
```

then you can obtain the validUser.

```
@Component
public class PhotoImportCommandDto extends BaseCommand {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("validUser")
    private User validUser;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to make annotations in Java. Anyway, in Spring, checking where the User exists in the DataBase or not is one line of code:

```
userRepository.findOne(user) == null
```

That is accomplished by the [`Spring Data JPA`](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa) project:

1. Create a JPA Entity `User`.
2. Set the `spring.datasource.url` and login/password in the
   `resources/application.properties`.
3. Create this interface:

   ```
   import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

   @Repository
   public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
   }
   ```

   Note, Spring implements it behind the scences.
4. Inject this interface into your `RestController` (or any other Spring bean):

   ```
       private UserRepository userRepository ;

   **constructor**(UserRepository ur){
       userRepository = ur;
   }
   ```

   Note, a Spring Bean is any class annotated `@Component` (this includes stereotype annotations like `Controller`, `Repository` - just look up the contents of an annotation, it may use `@Component` internally) or returned from a method which is annotated `@Bean` (can only be on the `Component` or `Configuration` class). A `Component` is injected by searching the classpath, `Bean` is injected more naturally.

Also note, `injecting` is specifying `@Autowired` annotation on field or constructor, on a factory method, or on a setter. The documentation recommends that you inject required dependencies into constructor and non-required into the setter.

Also note, if you're injecting into a constructor and it is clean by the arguments, you may omit `@Autowired` annotation, Spring will figure it out.

5. Call its method `findOne`.

So, you can do one of the following:

- Inject the `userRepository` into the `@RestController` constructor (as shown above). I would do that.
- Inject the `userRepository` into the `@Service` (internally `@Component`) class that will do this sorts of thing for you. Maybe you can play with it to create an annotation.

p.s. Use `@PostMapping` instead of `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`

p.p.s. If ever in doubt, go to the official documentation page and just press `CTRL-F`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/ Note the `current` word, that will always take you to the latest version.

p.p.p.s Each Spring project has its own `.io` webpage as well as quick `Get Started Guides` where you can quickly see the sample project with explanations expecting you to know nothing.

Hope that helps! :)

Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Using Jose's input, I took a bit of a different route.

Here's what I did:
I created a `ValidatedUser` class:

```
@RequestScope
@Component
public class ValidatedUser {

    private UserEntity user;

    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

and I also created a wrapper class `HttpRequestScopeConfig` to capture all variables to use over the course of an Http Request to the api.

```
@Component
public class HttpRequestScopeConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ValidatedUser validatedUser;
    ...
    public UserEntity getValidatedUser() {
        return validatedUser.getUser();
    }

    public void setValidatedUser(UserEntity validatedUser) {
        this.validatedUser.setUser(validatedUser);
    }
        ...
}
```

In my `UserExistsConstraintValidator` (which is the impl of `@UserExistsConstraint`, I set the validatedUser in the httpRequestScopeConfig:

```
public class UserExistsConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserExistsConstraint, Long> {

    //private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(EmailExistsConstraintValidator.class);

     @Autowired
     private UserCommandService svc;

     @Autowired
     private HttpRequestScopeConfig httpRequestScope;

     @Override
     public void initialize(UserExistsConstraint userId) {

     }

     @Override
     public boolean isValid(Long userIdField, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

      try {
       UserEntity user = svc.findUserOfAnyStatus((Long) userIdField);
       if (user != null) {
           httpRequestScope.setValidatedUser(user);
           return true;
       }
      } catch (Exception e) {
       //log.error(e);
      }
      return false;
     }

}
```

Now, I can access these variables throughout the rest of my service layers by autowiring `HttpRequestScopeConfig` where necessary.